# Multiple paypal account on one website.

Tags: paypal, integration

I just want to ask is there any way to use multiple paypal account on one site. 
I have different managers for different golf courses when a user booked teetime then the respective manager will pay on their own paypal account. 
Is this possible.? 
If yes then please let me know. 
Best regards. 
Husnain

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is if multiple paypal accounts can receive money on single web site because if it is multiple buyer then each buyer can login with their account and do the payment.

For receiving money it is possible. It depends on with which paypal product you have integrated.
For example some of the integration in paypal have "business" field which take PayPal email or payer id. Populate the paypal email which should receive the money in the business field.

Comment: which one provide this facility.?